# Is my interpretation for the product of random variables correct?

Tags: probability, random-variables

This may seem like a really easy problem but in the course of Probability and also in Statistics, we often encounter the product of random variables. So say $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both some random variables, how should one interpret the product of random variables, $X_1X_2$?

By definition, $X_i$ each is a function from $\Omega_i\to \mathbb{R}$. Hence am I right in thinking that $X_1X_2$ is defined only if $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$? If that is the case, suppose $\Omega_1=\Omega_2$ for now, am I therefore correct thinking that $X_1X_2$ is literally just a product of functions, where the multiplication is pointwise, from $\Omega_1\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is exactly that.